# Implementing desktop extension for a multi instance uwp app

Tags: uwp, windows-10, desktop-bridge

I followed [this](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/16/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-3/comment-page-1/#comment-18590) article to add desktop extension for my uwp app which is multi-instance. But I am getting deployment errors:

[Deployment Error Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtgxc.png)

Error   DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CF6] AppxManifest.xml(79,10): error 0x80080204: Cannot register the package because EntryPoint must be specified when SupportsMultipleInstances is true.

If I provide entrypoint same as my uwp app(UWP.App in this case) although there is no deployment errors but the appserviceconnection fails with this message:

[App not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEe4Q.png)

Any suggestion how I should go about this??

[Edit]

I made an out-proc AppService as described in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service) article and started it from full trust process following the same procedure in the article. But I can't seem to find any way to capture its instance from my uwp app. Any help??

Comment: Did you make your manifest entries in the appxmanifest file of the UWP project or the Packaging project? Once you add a packaging project, make sure you add the relevant entries in its appxmanifest file, because this is the one that gets ultimately included in the app package.

Comment: I added entries to the appxmanifest file of the packaging project as the example suggested.

Comment: Regarding your last edit: Not sure what you mean by "capture its instance". It runs in a separate process by design (out-of-proc). Bottom line is that you will need to keep track of your instances as you handle the cross-process communication between the desktop extension and UWP process (with or without out-of-proc appservice). The platform does facilitate this for you today.

Comment: My question is how do I keep track of an out-of-proc AppserviceConnection from my uwp app. The official guide doesn't seem to provide any way to do that.

Comment: You don't have access to the AppServiceConnection from the UWP app in the out-of-proc scenario because it lives in a different process. You can only access it from the background task process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create out-of-proc appservice as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service). Disable multi-instance for out-of-proc service. For each instance of uwp app create a new service. Create a static field in the background task class to store the appservice for desktop extension and initialize it when you create appservice from the desktop extension. Then you can pass messages from uwp app instances to out-of-proc appservice and then from appservice to desktop extension.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the steps you are following are not applicable to multi-instance UWP apps, because in-proc AppService is not supported for multi-instance apps. This is documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/multi-instance-uwp#background-tasks-and-multi-instancing

You can still launch a fulltrust process (desktop extension) from your multi-instance apps, but the cross-process communication as explained in the article you are following does not apply here. It's limited to standard, single-instance UWP applications.

Comment: Updated my question see if you can help.

Comment: Can you upvote my question so it gets more traction??

Comment: I am afraid there is not another answer to this. Maybe start a new question and be clear about the scenario you are trying to accomplish? As it stands it seems like you are looking for development help, but it's not clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I have got it working and has posted the answer here, you can reference this in your article if you want.